# Linux--back space stopped working in terminal

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard

My Backspace stopped backspacing and produced a `^?` instead.

Comment: Note that you can create an answer to your own question.

Comment: I just posted my answer as my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  I had both qterminal and lxterminal running at the same time and didn't realize it.

The command `stty -a` revealed that qterminal had `erase = ^H` and lxterminal had `erase = ^?`. The problem was happening in qterminal. Issueing the command `stty erase ^?` within qterminal solved the problem, temporarily. Then I started having problems in qterminal with `Space` not producing a space, but `Shift+Space` did produce a space.

Closing all qterminals and using only lxterminals fixed everything. Not sure why. Maybe someone else can give some insights.

See this qterminal issue: https://github.com/lxqt/qterminal/issues/770#issuecomment-748444889